# Get selected index for each row in DataGridViewRow collection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm looking to get the index of the selected item in the combobox that corresponds to a cell in the grid view.

The following is what I used:

```
var cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)row.Cells[1];
fieldIndex = cb.Items.IndexOf((string)cb.Value);
```

However, this doesn't taken into account the fact that the selected value may match another value in the combo box. How can I get the exact index that is selected for the current row?

Comment: For clarity, there are items that repeat in the `ComboBox.Items`? Such as `{ "Small", "Medium", "Large", "Small" }`?

Comment: Yes, there can be duplicate values in the item collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox doesn't actually exist unless the cell is selected. It is overlayed when the cell is active. You can access it in the `EditingControlShowing` event. For this reason you can't get the index unless you loop through the data source and check the value, but as you mentioned, you don't know which one you want since values can appear multiple times.
Generally you don't care about the index of the selection, you just care about the value. Are you sure you need the index? If you are properly using databinding against your grid, the backing collection will have its fields in sync with the grid and you have all the data you should care about.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! 
Yes, I still believe I need the index. I'm retrieving a list of fields from SharePoint. I want the internal name (unique), display name (not unique), and a field type. The combobox should only display the display name, but I need to know which internal name and field type I need.

Comment: to use when building my query based on those selections. 
The only other solution I was able to think of is showing the list of internal names which match the selected display name so that the user can then choose which one he/she wants.

Comment: @user3362735 On the combobox column, you can bind the `ValueMember` to the unique id and the `DisplayMember` to what you are currently using as "value". Then the user sees the friendly-version text, but the underlying data is set to the "ugly" id.

Comment: I looked up those properties and saw that this was exactly what I wanted. I just retrieved my data and stored it in a data table rather than a dictionary. This was a much more attractive approach and it allowed me to store all 3 fields without making a custom class. tldr: It works great! Thank you.